# php/js - Triggering a button when my timer is set to 00:00

Tags: javascript, php

I have found a js fiddle code that works just fine here it is.
HTML
`<div id="worked">00:05</div>`
JS

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
        var $worked = $("#worked");

        function update() {
            var myTime = $worked.html();
            var ss = myTime.split(":");
            var dt = new Date();
            dt.setHours(0);
            dt.setMinutes(ss[0]);
            dt.setSeconds(ss[1]);

            var dt2 = new Date(dt.valueOf() - 1000);
            var temp = dt2.toTimeString().split(" ");
            var ts = temp[0].split(":");

            $worked.html(ts[1]+":"+ts[2]);
            setTimeout(update, 1000);
        }

        setTimeout(update, 0000);
    });
```

Side-ops problem: When it reaches 0, it resets to 59:59 but doesn't matter for now.

How can I trigger this `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Test" onclick ="return show_confirm();">` to be submitted/clicked when the timer reaches 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1j13b0t/) which should do the job for you. It uses the following code:

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function (e) {
    var $worked = $("#worked");

    function update() {
        var myTime = $worked.html();
        var ss = myTime.split(":");
        var dt = new Date();
        dt.setHours(0);
        dt.setMinutes(ss[0]);
        dt.setSeconds(ss[1]);

        var dt2 = new Date(dt.valueOf() - 1000);
        var temp = dt2.toTimeString().split(" ");
        var ts = temp[0].split(":");
        if(ts[1] == 0 && ts[2] == 0)
            $( "#click" ).trigger( "click" );
        $worked.html(ts[1]+":"+ts[2]);
        setTimeout(update, 1000);
    }

    setTimeout(update, 0000);
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="worked">00:05</div>
<input id="click" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Test" onclick ="alert('hi');">
```

Comment: It's weird because when i try to apply this in my .php the JS isn't working.

Comment: Oh nevermind, i figured it out. Im just pissed why there is a script in the upper and lower part of the docs. Anyway, thank you mate